# Press enter key on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, enter

There is a texbox on a Fb groups. This is the html code:

```
<input type="text" class="inputtext textInput" name="freeform" 
       placeholder="Gruba Başkalarını Ekle" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" 
       aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead_list_u_jsonp_4_2" aria-haspopup="true" 
       role="combobox" spellcheck="false" aria-label="Gruba Başkalarını Ekle" 
       id="u_jsonp_4_3">
```

And I input a name by using javascript code.

```
document.getElementsByName('freeform')[0].value = '" + textBox2.Text + "';
```

But there is no button to click and I am using `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` event to click <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The problem is that `SendKeys.Send` is not enough for me and I wanna press <kbd>enter</kbd> key by using another ways.

How can I hit enter key without using `SendKeys.Send`?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in jQuery quite easily by creating an event and assigning the keyCode of the enter key, which is `13`:

```
var e = jQuery.Event('keydown');
e.which = 13;
$('input[name="freeform"]').trigger(e);
```

Comment: Can I do this by using javascript code instead of jQuery?